# Plotting model residuals and ignoring missing values in R to get proper white noise point cloud

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have data about co2 levels in time (`co2_mm_mlo$decimal_date` for time and `co2_mm_mlo$interpolated` for co2 levels) and I fitted a linear model using

`model<-lm(co2_mm_mlo$interpolated ~ co2_mm_mlo$decimal_date`)

and then plotted the time series and the model together.

[image: R plot]

Now I want to plot the residuals of the model in terms of the months (that are stored in `co2_mm_mlo$months`) using

`plot(co2_mm_mlo$months,resid(model))`

but because of some missong values I get a lot of good values and some seven outliers.

[image: Residuals]

How can I ignore those values to get a normal white noise point cloud?

Should I use na.action=na.pass somewhere?

**Update**: the data is from a [text file](ftp://aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/products/trends/co2/co2_mm_mlo.txt) that I had to download and I've renamed the variables inside to `date` `month` `decimal date` `average` etc. I imported the data from the file using File>import Dataset>From Text (base)...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe filter them out based on value? I don't have your data – it's helpful to post a reproducible example in your question with code + data + errors, etc. – so I made up an example below.

Here, I create a data frame, add some dodgy points, fit a linear model, and then look at the residuals. Based on this, I filter those residuals greater than 100 and replot.

```r
# Set RNG seed
set.seed(42)

# Create dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(time = seq(1960, 2010, by = 0.01))
df$value <- 1:nrow(df) + rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 10)

# Look at data
plot(df)
```

[image]

```r
# Add a few dodgy points
df[sample(1:nrow(df), 5), "value"] <- runif(5, 100, 1000)

# Run linear regression
fit <- lm(value ~ time, data = df)

# Plot residuals to identify outliers 
plot(df$time, resid(fit))
```

[image]

```r
# Filtering index
ind_filt <- abs(resid(fit)) < 100

# Filtered results
plot(df$time[ind_filt], resid(fit)[ind_filt])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this works when I plot time on the x axis and residuals on the y axis but since my original series has a non linear pattern the residuals aren't white noise, but I can understand why. If I want to plot months on the x axis then I get the message "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ".

Comment: @JohnCataldo It's difficult to solve the problem without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'd suggest updating your question with a reproducible example (i.e., include data using `dput`), so that we can take your data + code and replicate the difficulties you're having.